# Why $render never gets call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>CustomForms</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="triTemplate">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">No</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Not Sure</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
        .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.dataValue = "Not Sure";
        })
        .directive("triButton", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                require: "ngModel",
                template: document.querySelector("#triTemplate").outerText,
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    element.on("click", function (event) {
                        setSelected(event.target.innerText);
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ctrl.$setViewValue(event.target.innerText);
                        });
                    });

                    var setSelected = function (value) {
                        var buttons = element.find("button");
                        buttons.removeClass("btn-primary");
                        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                            if (buttons.eq(i).text() == value) {
                                buttons.eq(i).addClass("btn-primary");
                            } 
                        }
                    }

                    ctrl.$render = function () {
                        console.log("render");
                        setSelected(ctrl.$viewValue || "Not Sure");
                    }
                }



            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <div><tri-button ng-model="dataValue"/></div>
    <div class="well">
            Value:
            <select ng-model="dataValue">
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
                <option>Not Sure</option>
            </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I changed the value of select option, then the ctrl.$render gets called, but why when I click on button the ctrl.$render never gets called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$render` is only invoked if `$viewValue` has a different value from model. In your case, when `$setViewValue` is called, it will first set `$viewValue` and then the model to the same value. Because `$viewValue` is updated first, by the time AngularJS picks up the model change, it will see `$viewValue` has the same value and thus won't invoke `$render`.

If you want `$render` to be invoke, either force it like @SoluableNonagon pointed out or modify the click handler to change the model instead of invoking `$setViewValue`. This is the plunkr demonstrating the latter approach: http://plnkr.co/edit/uAqSxsAd49FkXa5Yu5Vs?p=preview. The relevant piece of code is:

```
var ngModelSet = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign                    

element.on("click", function (event) {
    setSelected(event.target.innerText);
    scope.$apply(function () {
      ngModelSet(scope, event.target.innerText)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about forcing it?
Why not call the render function inside the click event?

```
element.on("click", function (event) {
    setSelected(event.target.innerText);
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(event.target.innerText);
    });
    ctrl.$render();
});
```